# How to clean duplicate BB tags

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

```
[i][b][i][b](This is a paragraph with BBcode.)[/b][/i][/b][/i]
```

Some of my BB code has double tags, whats the best way to remove this?

I've tried a few things mostly regex, but I'm honestly a novice when it comes to regex.

Comment: But you provided not one single regex yourself. Plus: eliminating nested BBCodes can almost never be done via regex, you better do this with PHP alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely horrible, but it works.

```
<?php

$bb = '[i][b][i][b](This is a paragraph with BBcode.)[/b][/i][/b][/i]';

// regex with start, paragraph, and end capture groups
$regex = '#(?<start>(\[[a-z]*\])*+)(?<paragraph>.*)(?<end>(\[\/[a-z]*\])*+)#U';

// put matches into $matches array
preg_match_all($regex, $bb, $matches);

// get the stuff we need
$start = $matches['start'][0];         // string(12) "[i][b][i][b]"
$paragraph = implode('', $matches['paragraph']);

// now we will grab each tag
$regex = '#\[(?<tag>[a-z])\]#';
preg_match_all($regex, $start, $matches);
$tags = array_unique($matches['tag']);

// and build up the new string
$newString = '';
foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $newString .= '[' . $tag . ']';
}

// create the end tags
$end = str_replace('[', '[/', $newString);

// put it all together
$newString .= $paragraph . $end;

echo $newString; // [i][b](This is a paragraph with BBcode.)[/i][/b]
```

Which gives you `[i][b](This is a paragraph with BBcode.)[/i][/b]`

Check it here https://3v4l.org/O8UHO

Comment: Thanks this is pretty much what i did, but even worse than this, so ill mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to extract all the tags with a regexp (maybe like `/\[.*\]/U`) and then iterate throught them, removing all the duplicates

Quick example :

```
$bb = '[i][b][i][b](This is a paragraph with BBcode.)[/b][/i][/b][/i]';

preg_match_all('/(\[.*\])/gU', $bb, $tags);

$metTags = [];
foreach($tags[0] as $tag) {
    // tag has not been met, save it
    if (in_array($tag, $metTags) === false) {
        $metTags[] = $tag;
    // tag have been met already
    } else {
        // remove it ONCE
        $bb = preg_replace('#'.preg_quote($tag).'#', '', $bb, 1);
    }
}

echo $bb;
```

That is probably not the best solution due to preg_replace() use, but still doing the job great.

Edit : add code

Comment: using the ungreedy flag, that only returns the first tag https://regex101.com/r/UWTj3O/1

Answer (score 0):

So i wrote a long winded method in php only. It basically loops through all the characters, then i when i find an "[" i check the rest for accepted tags. I end up with an array of all the styles and just text allowing me to remove the duplicate styles. Would show code but dont want to get laughed at :D

Comment: check my solution, it's also horrible, but then i don't reckon regex is really the tool for this job. I can't resist a regex puzzle though lol